# REGEXP_SUBSTR Redshift - how to find the last substring

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, regexp-substr

I have a question regarding REGEXP_SUBSTR in redshift. I have a string, and I want to always return the last substring 'STATUS CHANGE FROM ''something'' TO ''another thing''. There might be multiple substring in the string. I only need to return the last one.

```
select REGEXP_substr(' sfdfgdfg STATUS CHANGE FROM ''REGISTERED'' TO ''DISABLED'' ZD# 17564 REASON: CUSTO STATUS CHANGE FROM ''DISABLED'' TO ''HOLD'' ', 'STATUS CHANGE FROM ''\w+'' TO ''\w+'' ');
```

The current code return nothing. Can someone help me take a look?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, I believe all you need is to anchor your pattern to the end of the line.  This is based on your one line of test data.  Note the dollar sign.

```
select REGEXP_substr(' sfdfgdfg STATUS CHANGE FROM ''REGISTERED'' TO ''DISABLED'' ZD# 17564 REASON: CUSTO STATUS CHANGE FROM ''DISABLED'' TO ''HOLD'' ', 'STATUS CHANGE FROM ''\w+'' TO ''\w+'' $');
```